# Select list option have some unexpected value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am generating selectlist option for setting stroke-opacity , like:

```
<label for="so">
    Stroke-opacity :</label>
<select id="so">
    @for (double i = 1; i >= 0; i-=0.1)
    {
        <option value="@i">@i</option>
    }
</select>
```

My problem is that, the last option (which should have value 0) have some unexpected value which is: `1.38777878078145E-16`. Can please anybody tell me whats going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a type of `decimal` instead of `double`.  [Since `double` is a floating-point number, it can lose precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx).

```
<label for="so">
    Stroke-opacity :</label>
<select id="so">
    @for (decimal i = 1M; i >= 0M; i-=0.1M)
    {
        <option value="@i">@i</option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select id="so">

<option value="1">1</option>
@for (int i = 9; i > 0; i--)
{
    string value = string.Format("0.{0}", i);

    <option value="@value">@value</option>
}
</select>
```